# How do you delete a document in xtdb with clojure?

Tags: clojure, xtdb

I can't find out how to delete a document in xtdb with clojure. I see the example in the cool interplanetary themed tutorial for deleting by time range or whatnot, but how do you just delete documents using similar syntax to how you would query? I realize it may not be similar syntax, but I should be able to, say, remove a todo from a db of todos, right?

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.xtdb.com/language-reference/datalog-transactions/#delete ?

Comment: Or https://docs.xtdb.com/language-reference/datalog-transactions/#evict ?

Comment: I hadn't seen those pages... I'll give them a go and it looks like they are going to work.